# Segmentation Fault Using Scanf ARM Assembly

Tags: assembly, arm, printf, scanf

I am new to assembly and have spent the past couple days scouring the internet for help but to no avail.

```
.data

format: .asciz "%s"
string: .asciz "Output: %s\n"

prompt: .asciz ">"

.text
.global main
.main:

    ldr r0, addr_prompt     /*loading address of prompt message in r0*/
    bl printf               /*calling printf*/   

    ldr r0, addr_format     /*loading first parameter of scanf*/
    ldr r1, addr_string     /*loading second parameter of scanf*/
    bl scanf                /*calling scanf*/

    /*below I am trying to print out the user 
    input from scanf*/

    ldr r1, [r1]            
    bl printf

    mov r7, #1
    swi 0

addr_prompt: .word prompt
addr_format: .word format
addr_string: .word string
```

When run, it gives a "Segmentation fault" error. Could someone inform me as to what I have done wrong, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Added comments to code as suggested and fixed copy error (scanf -> bl scanf)

Comment: Use a debugger and comment your code especially if you want others to help. Anyway, `scanf` should not even compile, looks like a copy-paste error you probably have `bl scanf` there. Please make sure you show us the code you are actually using. Also `ldr r1, [r1]` makes no sense and of  course you didn't comment what you wanted it to do so can't fix it for you. Note that `r1` is caller-saved so `scanf` will destroy it. You don't seem to know how `scanf` works in C at all (you didn't even pass a buffer for the return value).

Comment: Do your strings, etc work in C? is the problem your assembly language or the calls to the functions?  divide the problem in half.

Comment: Does it fault at `bl scanf`, and the `bl printf` works as expected with correct output (in debugger)? As I am even confused by `ldr r0, addr_prompt`, I would expect that one to be `ldr r0, prompt` only to load the address of symbol `prompt`, but then again this may be ARM assembler dialect I don't know yet, which may require some keyword to be used for direct load. Your indirection through `addr_prompt: .word prompt` is still very likely redundant, and it's not clear why you are using it (serves no obvious purpose for such short example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A buffer / storage is needed to store input data.

```
.data

format: .asciz "%s"

string: .asciz "Output: %s\n"
prompt: .asciz ">"

storage: .space 80          @ --- added buffer

.text
.global main
main:                       @ --- removed .

    ldr r0, addr_prompt     /*loading address of prompt message in r0*/
    bl printf               /*calling printf*/

    ldr r0, addr_format     /*loading first parameter of scanf*/
    ldr r1, addr_storage    @ --- location to write data from input
    bl scanf                /*calling scanf*/

    /*below I am trying to print out the user
    input from scanf*/

    ldr r1, addr_storage    @ --- data location
    ldr r0, addr_string     @ --- printf format
    bl printf

    mov r0, #0              @ --- good return code
    mov r7, #1
    swi 0

addr_prompt: .word prompt
addr_format: .word format
addr_string: .word string
addr_storage: .word storage @ --- address of buffer
```

Output from Raspberry Pi Raspbian:

```
as -o printf10.o printf10.s
gcc -o printf10 printf10.o

./printf10; echo $?
>Hello
Output: Hello
0
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I had no idea that a buffer was needed or how to implement it. Just for some extra clarification and understanding; the `80` that comes after `.space`, what is that referring to?

Comment: The buffer length is 80 characters long.